# Is silicon dioxide a polar molecule or not?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, polarity

Is $\ce{SiO2}$ is a polar molecule or not?
The difference in electronegativity between the two atoms is 1.7.

I read that $\ce{SiO2}$ doesn't exist as a single molecule in which the silicon atom is connected to four oxygen atoms. Can I consider it polar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\ce{SiO2}$ doesn't exist as a molecule rather exists as network of $\ce{Si}$ and $\ce{O}$ bonds with $\ce{Si}$ bonded to four $\ce{O}$ atoms. $\ce{SiO2}$ simply denotes their ratio in the complete structure. $\ce{Si-O}$ bonds are very polar but there are four $\ce{Si-O}$ bonds which cancel the dipole, making the structure as a whole, non-polar.

Comment: thanks a lot it's very now, one question if i may ask can attract or interaction happen with this molecule and other moleculue although SiO2 nonpolar.

Comment: Yes interactions can happen. Glass is made up of siO2 and we know glass and water are adhesive, as they form a concave meniscus. This is because of very weak bonds between the O atoms of sio2 and the H atoms of water.

Comment: thanks for the info. i was searching for this kind of explanation, so can i consider a some kind of  attraction even small one between SiO2 bonds and c=o bond ?

Comment: As c=o bond is polar, yes.

Comment: so it can be interaction between c=o and sio2, thank u so much for the clear info.

Comment: The meniscus is related to Si-OH groups on the surface of the SiO2 network covalent structure, see https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/30791/why-is-sand-glass-polar-how-does-lattice-structure-change-polarity/30798#30798. The process of silanizing derivatizes Si-OH groups into Si-OCH3 groups, making the sample's surface non-polar.